# LinearLayout inside gridlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

I have a `linearlayout` with `textview` and a `imageview` inside the `gridlayout`. I want linearlayout in column1 with the textview and imageview fitting properly in that column of the row. But the image view comes below the textview.

**Required result:**

[image]

**My output:**
[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
<GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayoutSuburb">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="Select "
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/selectImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change orientation vertical to horizontal  of your linear layout.simple.

Comment: Thanks, such a silly mistake, did not notice it first :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace** this attribute value of `LinearLayout`:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

**To**:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 3):

change your Linearlayout `orientation` to `android:orientation="horizontal"` from `android:orientation="vertical"`

Use

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Instead of

```
 android:orientation="vertical"
```

**CODE**

```
<GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayoutSuburb">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="Select "
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/selectImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change linear layout orientation to

> android:orientation="horizontal"

```
<GridLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="4"
android:columnCount="3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/gridLayoutSuburb">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="@color/blue">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Select "
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/selectImage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Your code to this

```
<GridLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="4"
android:columnCount="3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/gridLayoutSuburb">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="@color/blue">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Select "
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/selectImage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

User `android:orientation="horizontal"` and give android:width="0dp" so that the text remains in one line and doesn't increase it's width.

```
<GridLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:rowCount="4"
android:columnCount="3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/gridLayoutSuburb">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:background="@color/blue">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Select "
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/selectImage"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />
</LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change linearLayout1 orientation vertical to horizontal and add some margin among them:

```
<GridLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayoutSuburb">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="Select "
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/selectImage"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back" />
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```